# Des chaussures "tendances" ou "tendance" ?

Tags: accord

Est-ce qu'on accorde l'adjectif "tendance" ou non ? 
Je sais qu'on m'avait reprise à ce propos, mais je me rappelle plus si c'est parce que je l'avais accordé ou non.

Comment: Question rectifiée car telle qu'elle était rédigée c'était clairement du spam publicitaire.

Answer (score 5):

Un substantif souvent utilisé en apposition peut, avec le temps, donner naissance à un adjectif. Selon le [Larousse en ligne](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/tendance/77255?q=tendance#773765), *tendance* a passé ce cap – mais est encore invariable. Cette invariabilité est due au fait que la syntaxe d’origine, l’apposition, est toujours sensible. Elle l’est moins pour d’autres mots qui ont suivi le même parcours, mais plus anciens, comme *standard*, dont le même dictionnaire considère qu’il n’est que [« parfois considéré comme invariable en nombre »](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/standard/74453?q=standard#73614). *Victime* est un exemple de l’aboutissement de ce processus : pleinement adjectif et substantif, pleinement variable.

Mais si l’on considère que « tendance » est un substantif placé en apposition à « chaussures », et non un adjectif, alors, s’il ne prend pas la marque du pluriel, ce n’est pas pour la raison qu’il se trouve apposé, mais parce qu’il ne désigne pas plusieurs tendances. Car les substantifs apposés varient indépendamment l’un de l’autre, chacun selon son sens. Voici un autre exemple peut-être plus évident :

```
un sandwich boulettes
```

Souvent, les différents substantifs apposés désignent une même chose : il est alors logique que, lorsque l’un est au pluriel, l’autre le soit aussi. Comme dans l'exemple suivant, où chaque substantif désigne les mêmes individus :

```
des clowns acrobates
```

Mais il ne s’agit pas d’un accord : le choix du genre et du nombre d’un substantif est déterminé par ce qu’il désigne, et non par ses relations syntaxiques.

Answer (score 4):

*Tendance* est ici un nom juxtaposé à un autre nom qu’il complète. Il signifie  « selon la tendance actuelle ». Il reste donc invariable même s'il est juxtaposé à un nom pluriel.

> Des accessoires très tendance vous attendent au rayon Mode..

Voir la [BDLQ](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4423).

Bien sûr ceci n'empêche pas de nombreux blogueurs de faire l'erreur :

<strike>[Toutes les chaussures tendances de l'automne-hiver2016/2017](http://www.marieclaire.fr/,chaussures-automne-hiver,200118,49881.asp)</strike>

<strike>[Top 10 des couleurs tendances du printemps été 2017](http://www.cosmopolitan.fr/,pantone-les-couleurs-printemps-ete-2015,1904775.asp)</strike>

Comment: Exact! Cela veut dire que ces chaussures suivent la tendance d'aujourd'hui qui n'est pas forcément celle de demain ni celle d'hier.

Comment: +1 pour vos choix de "blogueurs" ! (et pour la précision de la réponse)

Answer (score 2):

« [Tendance](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tendance) » n'est pas un adjectif mais un substantif féminin.

Il n'y a donc pas de raison pour l'accorder.

Answer (score 1):

Comme mentionné par ailleurs, « Tendance » est et reste un substantif. Apposé à un autre nom, il s'accorde selon le sens (par syllepse) et il s'agit là d'une règle classique applicable à des centaines de tournures contemporaines dans lesquelles on supprime prépositions ou mots de liaison par souci  « d'efficacité ». Dans l'exemple donné, le singulier s'impose à l'évidence puisque si l'on reconstitue la tournure, on aurait *dans la tendance*.

Cela étant, la découverte (pour moi) est que Larousse développe un concept « d'adjectif invariable » qui me laisse aussi perplexe que préoccupé : pourquoi inventer un tel hybride alors que le nom en apposition est connu depuis longtemps ? Il semble bien être le seul à utiliser une telle qualification. Comment expliquer cela en classe aux enfants déjà confrontés à tant de bizarreries de la langue ?

Comment: Tout à fait d'accord avec cette remarque, et il ne faut pas donner plus de crédit que nécessaire à Larousse, surtout dans ce cas où le singulier  s'impose comme tu le dis. Mais par ailleurs il faut accepter qu'une langue soit quelque chose de vivant qui évolue, et donc oui, le français est une langue difficile à apprendre, autant pour les écoliers français que pour ceux qui apprennent le français comme langue étrangère.

Comment: Merci Laure pour cette confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

*tendance* est un substantif, utilisé comme adjectif (*de la dernière tendance ...*). On ne le décline pas en général, mais ceci prête à discussion.

autres exemples: *canon*, *culte*, *bateau*, *limite*.

voir [cette étude](http://www.persee.fr/doc/igram_0222-9838_2004_num_103_1_2543) sur le sujet des substantifs pseudo-adjectifs.